# NSMutableAttributedString with different fonts

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a problem with the combination of two strings:

```
let finalMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
let attributedDot = NSAttributedString(string: " ●", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 7)])
let firstPartString = NSAttributedString(string: "Sample text", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)])
finalMutableString.append(attributedDot)
finalMutableString.append(firstPartString)
label.attributedText = finalMutableString
```

And whole text has font size `7.0` not only `attributedDot`. 
Why is this how it behaves? Text's should have different sizes

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Except for the fact that `XCode` replaces `NSFontAttributeName` with `NSAttributedString.Key.font`.

Comment: This project is for Swift 3 so key.font probably is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your code work, but you think that it doesn't because font sizes look pretty much equally.

Here is what I see with your code

[image]

And that's what I see when I change size to `2` and `37`

[image]

And that's your original sizes (`7` and `17`), but for both strings, I've set the same text.

[image]

Comment: Ok I think this problem probably exist because I use ActiveLabel pod to achive active links because with normal UILabel it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way for Objective-C

```
NSMutableAttributedString *yourAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your string text"];

[yourAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Proxima Nova" size:18.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0,16)];
```

range should be length of your string